# Can't update from PHP 7.1 to PHP 7.2 on Mac

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

To be more precise, I don't even see where PHP 7.1 is installed.

When I run `php -v` in the terminal, I get:

```
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2019 22:19:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

So I thought I would use Homebrew to unlink 7.1 and install 7.2. Should be straightforward. However, running `brew unlink php71` returns an error saying:

```
No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php71
```

And, indeed, in `/usr/local/Cellar` there is nothing resembling a PHP version.

I tried running `brew update` and `brew upgrade` just in case, but it didn't help.

I also tried running a PHP application locally and did `phpinfo()` within the application, and I got the same version info I got in the console.

When I ran `whereis php` it gave me the result `/usr/bin/php`. When I ran `whereis php71` it came up with nothing which, I suppose, is to be expected in this situation.

The question is, how do I replace PHP 7.1 with 7.2 in the least painful way? Ideally, I would like to get `brew` to do this so I can update future version through `brew` as well.

Comment: Have you checked whether `/usr/bin/php` is a symlink?

Comment: No. What is this supposed to tell me?

Comment: @NicoHaase It is not a symlink, it is: `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root   wheel   11169664 May  4  2019 php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS has its own PHP version installed, which is complete independent from brew.

You need to force link your brew version.

```
brew link php@7.2 --force
```

Comment: But this will still kepp the 7.1 version floating around the system somewhere?

Comment: yes, but it will not be used. The Mac Version cannot be uninstalled, because it is part of the OS

Comment: And you're positive that, after I run this, I won't be in a situation where, for example, the command line version is 7.1 but in my application it's 7.2?

Comment: I did it, but php -v still gives version 7.1. Do I need to update my path or something?

Comment: Tried restarting apache but still no change.

Comment: you only mentioned the cli, nothing from apache. thats a complete different part.
Please search for one of the many tutorial how to setup apache/php in mac.

Comment: I referenced Apache indirectly when I referenced running a PHP application and phpinfo().